# Inno Setup Compiler: How to use a constant within a event method?

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following click event method and I am trying to use the `{pf}` constant within this method.

How can the constant be used?

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  // always allow move through the wizard pages
  Result := True;
  // if we are on the final page, run list is visible and the first item
  // in the run list (our fake check box) is checked, then...
  if (CurPageID = wpFinished) and (WizardForm.RunList.Visible) and
    (WizardForm.RunList.Checked[0]) then
  begin
    // execute application you need here (I like calc.exe :) and wait for
    // its termination for a specified time (here 5000 ms); if the calc.exe
    // will be closed in 5 seconds, a default browser will navigate to the
    // Google page, otherwise the setup just quit (keeping calc.exe running)
    if ShellExecWait('', {pf}'\wampmanager.exe', '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, 5000) then
      ShellExec('', 'http://localhost/cow', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first expand the constant value e.g. by using [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) function:

```
SomeFunctionWithFileParameter(ExpandConstant('{pf}\wampmanager.exe'));
```

Comment: ok, this works; now, how do i get the url where the app has been installed?

Comment: Uhm, URL ? I think you mean just path, where the user chose to install the application. If so, then what the user enters in the *Select Destination Location* page can be expanded from the [`{app}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=app) constant.